# Why flatMap is implemented with merge in RxJava?

Tags: rx-java, rx-android, flatmap

Why is RxJava 1.x flatMap() operator is implemented with merge?

```
public final <R> Observable<R> flatMap(Func1<? super T, ? extends Observable<? extends R>> func) {
        if (getClass() == ScalarSynchronousObservable.class) {
            return ((ScalarSynchronousObservable<T>)this).scalarFlatMap(func);
        }
        return merge(map(func));
    }
```

From flatMap() call I can return only one Observable that conforms to `<? extends Observable<? extends R>>`. Than map(func) call wraps it into another Observable, so that we have something like this `Observable<? extends Observable<? extends R>>`. That makes me thinking that merge() call after map(func) is unnecessary.

The merge() operator is said to perform the following:

> Flattens an Observable that emits Observables into a single Observable
>   that emits the items emitted by those Observables, without any
>   transformation.

Now inside the flat map we can only have an Observable that emits one Observable. Why merge? What am I missing here?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at the signatures might help:

Imagine that with an `Observable<String>` you want to `flatMap` to the individual characters. The way of doing that with flatMap is:

```
Observable.just("foo", "hello")
          .flatMap(s -> Observable.from(s.split("")))
```

What's the type of this Observable? It is an `Observable<String>`.

Now instead of using `flatMap`, use `map` **with the same function**. What's the type?

```
Observable.just("foo", "hello")
          .map(s -> Observable.from(s.split("")))
```

You'll see that it is actually `Observable<Observable<String>>`...
And if we subscribe to this observable and print out the emitted items, we get this:

```
rx.Observable@5b275dab
rx.Observable@61832929
```

Not very useful. Worse, these `Observable`s haven't been subscribed to, so they won't emit any data :(

We see that the goal of `flatMap` is to let the function produce an inner `Observable<T>` per source item, and then subscribe to these inner observables and flatten their emission together in the output `Observable<T>`. And `merge` does just that!

To verify that, wrap the above map result in an `Observable.merge(...)`:

```
Observable<Observable<String>> mapped = 
    Observable.just("foo", "hello")
              .map(s -> Observable.from(s.split("")));

Observable.merge(mapped)
          .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

This outputs:

```
f
o
o
h
e
l
l
o
```

Answer (score 1):

> Now inside the flat map we can only have an Observable that emits one Observable.

No - you have one observable that emits one observable *per source observable item*. So if your source observable has more items, you are going to have multiple observables emited.

That's why you need `merge()`.